# HTTPS redirect to previous domain after changing domain

Tags: magento-1.7

After transferring the file from another server and changing the domain. the https  still redirects to previous domain, i already updated the secure_url in system > configuration > web to the current url. I also try to clear cache and reindex but the problem is still there. everything in the website is okay except https.

Hoping for your help guys.
thank you.

**UPDATE 11/08/2015**

I change the value from `core_config_data table`, i don't know why but the default secure_url is still the previous domain even i already change it in the `system > config`..

Comment: Have you tried different browser? Chrome (for one) will cache redirects. So it *may* be it is your browser doing the redirect.

Comment: Most probably the answer is very easy. Maybe you forget to clean cache, didn't save the value or smth else.